# The div doesn't fill the space

Tags: html, css, border

I'm creating a website and I have a problem with borders and dimensions.

The problem consists in a container (display:flex) with several children, but the side borders of them despite having height: 100% do not cover the chosen space.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 10vh;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(218, 165, 32, 1);
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

nav>div {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 150%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="titolo">hairdresser</div>
</header>
<nav>
  <div>home</div>
  <div>storia del negozio</div>
  <div>shop</div>
  <div>servizi</div>
  <div>iscriviti</div>
  <div>registrati</div>
</nav>
<main>
  <div class="lato-destro">
    gggg
  </div>
  <div class="lato-sinistro">
    hhhh
  </div>
  <div class="centro">
    kkkk
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
</footer>
```

[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPnZa.png)

I tried to change the property box-sizing: content-box to box-sizing: border-box , but the result got me nowhere.

[Website with border-box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFtqe.png)

I also deprived to change some flex properties, but without solving the problem.

This is the code whit the border around the div
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qqvp.png)

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet which shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There's not enough code to see the problem you're having..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your divs do not need to be assigned a `display: flex` value since they are the flex-items within the parent flex container.  Remove the line of code `display: flex` from your nav > div{} CSS, as well as `justify-content` and `align-items` since your divs don't contain any flex-children themselves.

Next, we will want to tell our flex children how to behave.  To do this, we assign them a flex-grow value of 1, so add `flex-grow: 1` to nav > div, which will allow them to grow to fill the max allowable size of .

In the example below I removed the text and added `box-sizing: borderbox` to demonstrate this.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 10vh;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(218, 165, 32, 1);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

nav>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 150%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="titolo">hairdresser</div>
</header>
<nav>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</nav>
<main>
  <div class="lato-destro">
    gggg
  </div>
  <div class="lato-sinistro">
    hhhh
  </div>
  <div class="centro">
    kkkk
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Happy to help! You may consider marking my reply as an answer so it closes the question and lets others know it is answered as well.  Happy New Year!